# How to project simple data set into to anonymous type of a different shape

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, anonymous-types, projection

I have a simple set of data that I am having trouble figuring out how to create the projection I want using LINQ.

```
public class Score {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Value { get; set; }
}

var scores = new List<Score> {
  new Score { Name = "jesse", Value = 10 },
  new Score { Name = "jesse", Value = 12 },
  new Score { Name = "jesse", Value = 15 },
  new Score { Name = "billy", Value = 5 },
  new Score { Name = "billy", Value = 7 },
  new Score { Name = "billy", Value = 20 },
  new Score { Name = "colin", Value = 25 },
  new Score { Name = "colin", Value = 13 },
  new Score { Name = "colin", Value = 8 }
};
```

I need to project 'scores' into an anonymous type with the following structure.

```
{
  series : [
    { name : "jesse", data : [10, 12, 15 ] },
    { name : "billy", data : [ 5,  7, 20 ] },
    { name : "colin", data : [25, 13,  8 ] }
  ]
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var result = new {
    series = from score in scores
           group score.Value by score.Name into nameValues
           select new
           {
             name = nameValues.Key,
             data = nameValues
           }
};
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! I changed your answer slightly so that it projects the exact shape I was looking for, but the `group-by-into` statement was really the key here.

Answer (score 1):

Does this match the structure you want?

```
var query = scores.GroupBy(s => s.Name);
var result = query.Select(q => new {
    Name = q.Key, 
    Data = q.ToArray().Select(k => k.Value)
});
var anotherAnon = new {series = result.ToArray()};
```

Comment: Yes it does. I edited your answer to reflect an edit I made to my contrived example. Thanks.